# Скрывает ли nginx proxy_pass реальный ip?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, proxy

Необходимо скрыть реальный адрес сайта. Хочу сделать через отдачу сайта с другого сервера, прописав в конфиге nginx proxy_pass - ip:port другого сервера (ну и через firewall запретить другие подключения на оригинальном сервере).
Вопрос - скроет ли это реальный адрес сайта? Можно ли как-то определить, что запрос перенаправляется на другой ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. да - скроет.
2. нет - только по каким-нть уж очень косвенным признакам.